# Azure free website stopped even though I have upgraded subscription

Tags: azure, subscription, trial

My web site has been stopped and I have a warning icon as shown here:

[image]

I have signed up for the free trial and I have also upgraded the account subsequently.
But the warning icon is still there and the

When I click the 3-month Free Trial link I get this:

[image]

Looks like everything is fine. So why does my website not start?

When I go to the "Manage administrators" page I get this:

[image]

Two users! The mail-adresses are identical. The ID's are not.
I'm not sure how this happened and what I can do about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded, you created a new subscription. Your original app is running in the trial, and your new app is running in your new Pay-As-You-Go subscription. You just need to redeploy your app from free trial to pay-as-you-go. If you have anything in Blob storage (such as a Virtual Machine VHD), you can very easily copy that over to a new storage account with asynchronous blob copy (easily done in either PowerShell or universal command line tools for Mac/Linux/Windows).

Comment: Can you tell me how to "redeploy the app". The only option I can find is to create a new website. In this case I have to use a new url. (using the free mode). I would very much like to keep the current url.

Comment: @Nikolaj the URL (xyz.azurewebsites.net) is created with the website, so you can delete the one you were using and then enter it again for the new website